# We are searching for ACH Bank Payment gateway like transferwise.com

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, lumen

We want to integrate Payment gateway like **transferwise.com**. We like to use for investment or equity type project application.where  borrower post loan for his requirement and investor do investment on loan.once borrower get all required funds then using **ACH payment system** we will directly debited EMI to borrower bank account and transfer to Investor account.
let me know anyone has idea about this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [OpenACH](http://openach.com/) if it can do what you are looking for? I once installed the solution for a client. You can schedule ACH payment, and do a whole lots of stuffs.